# Converting string to int in javascript returns NaN

Tags: javascript, string, casting, innerhtml

I am trying to convert a phone number on a web page into an integer value but it repeatedly returns NaN, despite being a number. This is part of a chrome extension. My code is as follows:

```
currNum = String(document.getElementsByClassName("number")[0].innerHTML).trim()
console.log("First: " + currNum)

currNum = currNum.replace("(","").replace(")","").replace("-","").replace(" ","")
console.log("Second: " + currNum)

currNum = parseInt(currNum)
console.log("Third: " + currNum)
```

The logged output is:

```
‪First: ‪(206) 000-0000
Second: ‪2060000000
Third: ‪NaN
```

Is there something about this number that can't be cast to an int?

Thanks

Comment: There's a special non-visible character at the start of the `currNum` value. It's probably there in your source HTML content also; in fact that's the only place it could have come from.

Comment: Specifically it's character 202A, the "left-to-right embedding" character. That will cause `parseInt()` to fail.

Comment: To your `.replace()` chain you can add `.replace(/[^ -~]/g, "")` to get rid of it

Comment: There's a [✥Note](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71316919/2813224) added about the placement of the hyphen in the regex. It's just a precaution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regex (ie [`/[()\s-]/g`](https://regex101.com/r/gSR78P/1))<sup>✥</sup> as the first param of `.replace()` and instead of `" "` for a space, use `\s` which will match all types of whitespace (including the [202A](https://unicode-table.com/en/202A/), Pointy mentioned). Also, replace `.innerHTML` with `.textContent`.

<sup>✥**Note:** [`/[()\s-]/g`](https://regex101.com/r/gSR78P/1) will match each `(`, `)`, `-`, and whitespace. Place the `-` at the end of expression or it could be misinterpreted as a range.</sup>

```js
let currNum = String(document.querySelector(".number").textContent).trim()
console.log("First: " + currNum)

currNum = currNum.replace(/[()\s-]/g,"");
console.log("Second: " + currNum)

currNum = parseInt(currNum)
console.log("Third: " + currNum)
```

```html
<address>
  <p class='number'>(206) 555-0000</p>
</address>
```

Comment: Well the plain space (" ") is character 32 (decimal; 0x20) in the basic Latin page, so `[^ -~]` will reliably strip out any character codes that don't fall into the basic page visible (non-"control") character range.

Comment: However of course the code you have will also work.

Comment: oh I see you're knocking them out with one replace, carry on then.

Comment: Never occured to me to use the literal space as a class, clever.

Answer (score -1):

```
currNum = currNum.replace(/[\s()-]/g, '')
```